# uclinux on cortex development board no sound using alsa

Tags: alsa, cortex-m, uclinux

I'm trying to run aplay on uclinux that running on STM32F7 emcraft developer board,
the board is connected to usb audio card and when trying to use aplay to play audio file nothing is coming from the speakers, the command that i'm running is

> aplay -D hwplug:2,0 audio.wav

the output is

> Playing WAVE 'audio.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 16000 Hz,
>   Mono

and nothing is playing, and its much slower then it should be about 2 seconds when the audio length is about half a second.

when trying to play with `default:CARD=Device` getting the next error

> ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1000:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to create IPC shm
>   instance

and with  `front:CARD=Device,DEV=0` getting this

> aplay: set_params:1087: Channels count non available

so the only device that work but no sound is comming out is "plughw:2"

the output of aplay -L is:

```
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
default:CARD=Dummy
    Dummy, Dummy PCM
    Default Audio Device
sysdefault:CARD=Dummy
    Dummy, Dummy PCM
    Default Audio Device
default:CARD=Loopback
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    Default Audio Device
sysdefault:CARD=Loopback
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    Default Audio Device
default:CARD=Device
    USB Audio Device, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
sysdefault:CARD=Device
    USB Audio Device, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB Audio Device, USB Audio
    Front speakers
surround40:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB Audio Device, USB Audio
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB Audio Device, USB Audio
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB Audio Device, USB Audio
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB Audio Device, USB Audio
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB Audio Device, USB Audio
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB Audio Device, USB Audio
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
```

I tried to use alsa api with the same resualt as aplay the code is reading the audio file in chunks and using "snd_pcm_writei" to play it, on the 5 loop the code is freezing and after about a second the control returns to the OS.

the only thing is working is arecord that is recording audio with no problems.

I tried to use different usb sound card, getting the same behavior.

where should I be looking for the problem?

Comment: Check if the wave file audio parameter are correct . Is it really Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 16000 Hz, Mono. Generally aplay will parse the wav file header and than prints the information of format , sampling frequency and channels... Have you tried any other wav file ?

Comment: I tried to play a wave file that exactly matches the direct hw device, rate 44100 and 2 channels, the aplay prints "Playing WAVE 'audio.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 44100 Hz, Stereo" but still nothing comes out.